# Can someone explain output in terminal after excecute jarfile

Tags: java, jar, git-bash

After I execute jarfile I need to explain the output but I dont know what is

```
"[20:32:38.205281900] D:\10\src\out\artifacts\10_jar\newDir\test.txt"
```

after use

```
java -jar 10.jar
```

And the number keep change if I execute more, can somone explain to me please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with some more information about your problem. Provide us with some code examples or output listings so we could be more helpfull.

Comment: It obviously prints some timestamp and a name of file

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in brackets is a [Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp).

Please, be more careful when posting a question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.